# Getting TypeError: string indices must be integers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fetch data using API from a website. [Thousandeyes API](http://developer.thousandeyes.com/v6/usage/)

My code is given below :

```
import requests
import json
import urllib2, base64
import sys

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'http://proxy.wdf.sap.corp:8080'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

username='xxx@xxx.com' # API Username
password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' # API Password Token Code
THOUSANDEYES_API_URL='https://api.thousandeyes.com/v6/usage.json'


request = urllib2.Request(THOUSANDEYES_API_URL)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = json.load(result)

#save output in text file

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open ('usage.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

#print data

for i in data['usage']:
        print "Month Start: " + i['monthStart']
        print "Month End: " + i['monthEnd']
        print "Account Group Name:  " + i['accountGroupName']
        print "Test Name: " + i['testName']
        print "\n"

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

When I am running this script, I am getting below mention error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./te_license_usage.py",
>   line 32, in 
>       print "Month Start: " + i['monthStart'] TypeError: string indices must be integers

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a set of dummy data returned. The site requests for login credentials

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over your `data`.It is not a list.

**Try:**

```
print "Month Start: " + data['usage']["quota"]['monthStart']         #Key "quota"
print "Month Start: " + data['usage']["quota"]['monthEnd']
for j in data['usage']['tests']:                                     #Iterate Key 'tests'
    print "Account Group Name:  " + j['accountGroupName']
    print "Test Name: " + j['testName']
```

**Output:**

```
Month Start: 2016-04-28 00:00:00
Month Start: 2016-05-28 00:00:00
Account Group Name:  Documentation
Test Name: https://app.thousandeyes.com
Account Group Name:  Documentation
Test Name: https://support.thousandeyes.com
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for your kind support. I am still getting same error.

Comment: for i in data['usage']:
        print "Month Start: " + i["quota"]['monthStart']
        print "Month End: " + i["quota"]['monthEnd']
        for j in i['tests']:
                print "Account Group Name:  " + j['accountGroupName']
                print "Test Name: " + j['testName']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./te_license_usage.py", line 32, in <module>
    print "Month Start: " + i["quota"]['monthStart']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: Great. It is working now. Thanks Rakesh for your great support.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

`data['usage']` contains a list which as shown in your error:

```
 print "Month Start: " + i['monthStart'] TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

so use `data['usage'][0]`:

```
for i in data['usage'][0]:
    print "Month Start: " + i['monthStart']
    print "Month End: " + i['monthEnd']
    print "Account Group Name:  " + i['accountGroupName']
    print "Test Name: " + i['testName']
    print "\n"
```

Comment: Hi It's not working. Getting below error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./te_license_usage.py", line 31, in <module>
    for i in data['usage'][0]:
KeyError: 0